# Unable to convert text to Numbers

Tags: excel

I've been given an excel to import on Database, it was exported from an Access DB. in the excel there's a column `type_class`, in one excel it's good(sheet1), but on another excel which I moved to sheet2 to make `VLOOKUP` function, I can't tell whether it's a text or a number column from the first sight. the upper-left green-thing is not showing on all cells. but, using `ISTEXT` function result in `text`. below is the original column without any changes or formatting, as well as `ISTEXT` result.
[image: ![[enter image description here] [image]

when I use the column in a `VLOOKUB` function to transfer the Name to the first sheet, only (1010, 1101, 1102,....), hence the cells with the green-mark on the upper-left corner.
[image]

I can easly format the key in sheet1 using `text-to-columns`, cell formatting, and any other way.
but I cannot change the column in sheet2, I tried:

- Text-to-Columns
- Cell Formatting
- VALUE(text), CLEAN(text), TRIM(text), TRIM(CLEAN(text)), CLEAN(SUBSTITUTE())
- Multiply by 1

but only the cell with the green-mark changes to a number, the rest stays the same. I browsed the internet but didn't get a solution either.
[image]

Edit:
I uploaded what is need to test the case on the drive. you can find it [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZVshc2NneYMRcTE_BTa9Ydo0mzPcGrTa/view?usp=sharing)
Help Appreciated

Comment: Perhaps there are some non-printing characters in the cells where you cannot convert text to numbers.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, I tried `CLEAN()`, `TRIM(CLEAN)`, `CLEAN(SUBSTITUTE)`. NONE has worked

Comment: First you need to figure out what is in there. Those functions won't work with many non-printing characters.  Do a simple `=LEN(cell_ref)` to see if this assumption is correct. Then use `MID` to figure out what the character is.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, result is 6 for cells where I cannot convert text to numbers, and for in the others. `MID` result in the same exact column, `MID(0810)` results `0810`. I have editted my answer and added a sample excel uploaded in google drive. realy appreciate your help

Comment: I don't see any link to a file, but see my answer for a troubleshooting method.  Your `LEN` formula results proves that there are extraneous characters in your non-convertible digit strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your digit strings that you can't convert to text, from the comments it seems there are extra characters in that string not removable by `TRIM` or `CLEAN`.

- Determine what those character are

  - Assume a "non-convertible" digit string is in `A1`
  - Enter the following formula

    - `B1: =MID($A$1,ROWS($1:1),1)`  and fill down
    - `C1: = UNICODE(B1)`  and fill down
  - From this you can determine the character to use in a `SUBSTITUTE` function.

For example:

[image]

From the above we see that the character code that we need to get rid of is `160`.

So we use:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(160),"")
```

or, to convert it in one step to a number:

```
=--SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(160),"")
```

***Note** If the character code is >255, use `UNICHAR` instead of `CHAR` in the `SUBSTITUTE` function.*

Comment: Worked like a Charm. The character code was `8207` for some cells and `8206` for others. Thank you for your help

Comment: @adelsameer Glad to help. And those codes are quite interesting. They are used to precisely define whether the node should be rendered `left-to-right` or `right-to-left`. So, perhaps, at some time, the numbers were embedded in a phrase rendered `right-to-left` and had to be rendered `left-to-right`.

Answer (score 0):

Without an example, I use value() to convert what excel takes as text like so:

```
=value(left(“10kg”,2))
```

Or the following also works:

```
=left(“10kg”,2)*1
```

Note those double quotes should be the straight ones - sorry smartphone is not always smart...

And if leading or trailing spaces are an issue, then trim() is one solution.